# A closed unbounded filter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

For $A$ an uncountable set let $${\cal S}_{\aleph_0} (A)=\{s:s\subseteq  A,|s|\leq \aleph_0\}.$$
Now let $${\cal D}_{\aleph_0}(A)$$ be the filter of all subsets of ${\cal S}_{\aleph_0} (A)$ which include a closed unbounded set.

Can a good sense be given to this stuff: $${\cal D}_{\lambda}(A)$$ where $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal ? Is this alleged sense unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context that you’ve given I would expect that $|A|>\lambda$ and understand $\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}(A)$ as follows.

$\mathcal{S}_\lambda(A)=\{s\subseteq A:|s|\le\lambda\}$. $C\subseteq\mathcal{S}_{\lambda}(A)$ is unbounded if for each $s\in\mathcal{S}_{\lambda}(A)$ there is an $x\in C$ such that $s\subseteq x$. $C$ is closed if $\bigcup E\in C$ whenever $E$ is a $\subseteq$-increasing chain in $C$ of length $<\lambda^+$. $\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}(A)$ is the filter on $\mathcal{S}_\lambda(A)$ generated by the collection of all closed, unbounded subsets of $\mathcal{S}_\lambda(A)$: $D\in\mathcal{D}_\lambda(A)$ iff there is a closed, unbounded $C\in\mathcal{S}_\lambda(A)$ such that $C\subseteq D$.